# Phone screen rotation button in full screen mode

Tags: javascript, html, screen

When the user presses the button, the screen turns from vertical to horizontal, and when you click the exit button from full screen mode it returns from horizontal to vertical [Example](http://jsfiddle.net/4vfek3cr/)

```js
var elem = document.documentElement;
function openFullscreen() {
  if (elem.requestFullscreen) {
    elem.requestFullscreen();
  } else if (elem.webkitRequestFullscreen) { /* Safari */
    elem.webkitRequestFullscreen();
  } else if (elem.msRequestFullscreen) { /* IE11 */
    elem.msRequestFullscreen();
  }
}

function closeFullscreen() {
  if (document.exitFullscreen) {
    document.exitFullscreen();
  } else if (document.webkitExitFullscreen) { /* Safari */
    document.webkitExitFullscreen();
  } else if (document.msExitFullscreen) { /* IE11 */
    document.msExitFullscreen();
  }
}
```

```html
<button onclick="openFullscreen();">Open Fullscreen</button>
<button onclick="closeFullscreen();">Close Fullscreen</button>
```

I need a way to rotate the screen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```html
<script>
function openFullscreen() {
 document.body.requestFullscreen();
 screen.orientation.lock("landscape");

}

function closeFullscreen() {
screen.orientation.lock("portrait");  } 

function closeFullscreen() { document.exitFullscreen();  } 

</script>

<button onclick="openFullscreen();">Open Fullscreen</button>
<button onclick="closeFullscreen();">Close Fullscreen</button>
```